# Can Single Sign-on be achieved between two applications secured by different STSs using OpenID Connect with Federation

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, identityserver4, federated-identity

I have a web application secured by IdentityServer using OpenID Connect. It is to be launched from Microsoft CRM and I would like to know whether SSO can be achieved by federating IdentityServer to the Azure AD that secures CRM? Specifically, I would like know if there is a mechanism to pass a hint from CRM to our application so that IdentityServer would not have to display the login screen and would simply direct the authorization request onto the Azure AD where the CRM user is authenticated? The OpenID Connect protocol defines a "login_hint" that IdentityServer4 appears to implement within its interactionservice, but I am not sure this was the intent of this parameter and how CRM could pass this parameter to our application, which would then have to pass it on to IdentityServer.

One additional wrinkle, our application is multi-tenant and will be launched from multiple CRM instances. Therefore, I suspect the CRM "hint" would have to reference the Azure TenantId so the correct Azure AD routing could be achieved. However, maybe the Azure "common" endpoint could be used so the multiplexer could route the request to the appropriate Azure AD? If so, I am guessing that CRM would also have to pass the CRM username so the multiplexer would know the appropriate Azure AD?

As you can likely guess from all my questions, I am relatively new to security and have no idea what is possible and what path(s) could lead to success.

Comment: The short answer is that IDS4 is just a framework so you're free to put whatever authentication flows you like in place really. I suppose it hinges on what you can get CRM to send over. Is using Azure AD directly an option or do you already have IDS4 in play and this is just an additional integration for an existing app?

Comment: We currently have Azure AD in play, but are looking for a platform agnostic STS. Since I am new to security, I am having difficulty understanding the request flow to achieve the outcome I desire. I plan on using the IdentityServer4 Samples today to trace the flow through the code to try and make sense of what I need to do.